# setListAdapter within MainActivity

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm trying to get my listview to work with json and in my MainActivity. I have an error on my **onPostExecute(string result) method**. It gives me the following error: "The method setListAdapter(CustomAdapter) is undefined for the type MainActivity.getTweets".   I have the following:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class Main Activity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<TweetDetailClass> tweets = new ArrayList<TweetDetailClass>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { .. }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { .. }

    public void searchTwitter(View view){
        ...
        new GetTweets().execute(searchURL);
    }

    public class GetTweets extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        protected String doInBackground(String... twitterURL){ .. }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview, tweets));
        }
    }  
}
```

**CustomAdapter Constructor**

```
CustomAdapter(Context c, int textView, ArrayList<TweetDetailClass> data){
    //_data = data;
    //_c = c;
    super(c, textView, data);
    this._data = data;
}
```

Thanks for your help! I'm a beginner so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setListAdapter()` can only be used if your `Activity` extends `ListActivity` and I think your  xml layout must contain a `ListView` object with the id "@android:id/list".

Alternativelly, if your `Activity` extends `Activity` you should set the adapter like:

```
yourListView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview, tweets));
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks!, theres no more errors, but I'm not retrieving any tweets which is strange. Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Hummm... Just make sure your are implementing the method `getCount()` (I guess this is the name) inside the adapter. Make it return the number of rows you want in the list.

Answer (score 1):

`setListAdapter()` is a method on `ListActivity`. Your activity (whose name apparently is the invalid `Main Activity`) appears to inherit from `Activity`, not `ListActivity`.

Comment: I changed it to ListActivity, but my app crashes when opened. IS there any way around this?

Comment: The ListView in your xml file needs to have a specific id:

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" ... />